# Access call log in iOS4 - possible?

Tags: iphone, ios4, calllog

I know that it isn't possible to access the Call Log on iOS less than 4.

My question is about the new OS - is it already possible?

Comment: Unless you have a jailbroken phone. In which case you can use this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible