# Call history, SMS history, Email history in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have one requirement to fetch all the call logs, SMS logs and Email logs in iOS. So, if anyone have any idea about how to fetch call or sms or email logs (history) in iOS, please help me or suggest me the solution or whether it is feasible or not.

But one app is also available in app store.

App name is **[calLog](http://itunes.apple.com/app/callog/id327883585?ign-mpt=uo=6&mt=8)**.

Some website like "[Accessing iPhone Call History](http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)" also says, it's possible, how's it true?

Thanks in advance to all. :)

Comment: The app you are linking to just replicates all the caller functions inside the app. This isn't getting the call logs or any other logs from the phone, it is just that you are initiating a call from within that app and so it records the number you dialled.

Comment: See also [iPhone call log / history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history)

Answer (score 17):

No, its not possible to fetch `Call/SMS/Email` logs in iOS.

**You can do this in jailbroken device.**

Comment: I know very well how to accept the ans. But you can see my updated question. OK....

Comment: The calLog application is not fetching the call-log from the in-built Phone app. This application is using its own calling API like the VOIP calls and storing those call records.

Comment: It is possible for jailbroken devices. If you use these private APIs Apple will reject your application.

Answer (score 3):

http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/ shows you how to access the call history. It is possible but Apple may not accept your App into their Store if they discover it. Sometimes Apps slip thru the cracks and get published even if they are against Apple's guidelines. Remember Tether? It was available for a day before Apple pulled it. Path was uploading your contacts before getting caught and then they updated their App.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible to fetch the call or sms history in **iOS** device..but it is **possible** in **older iOS version** by using **call_history.db** file which contains all **call history** of iOS device

Answer (score 1):

Hi,friends.

Do you have backup files in your PC?

If you have installed iTunes on your computer, then you can run it and sync it with your iPhone, after that, all of your iphone data can be backed-up in your iTunes. If you want to  fetch all of them, then you jsut need to open the folders of the targeted files containing your messages ,contacts, call logs, and then drag them to your computer! Done!.

If you can not find those messages or call logs or contacts you want, that maybe results from these reasons: you did not backed up successfully or those information lost because of some physical problem. Then you can have a try on some recovery software to search the lost data. If you install the recovery program onto your PC ,you can preview all of your phone data, including the deleted ones!.

Hope this method help you all !

Answer (score 0):

Call log is possible since this app does that: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navita-t.e.m.-personal/id590228620?mt=8 application does that. The question is, how?

Btw, SMS log and Email history I don't think it's possible.