# Add VOIP Call History to call log IOS

Tags: iphone, ios7, call, voip

I want to add call history of VOIP application to Iphone  call log.But i don't know how to do it,whether apple will accept it.The only resource i found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822031/call-history-sms-history-email-history-in-ios).Even the above link didn't gave a proper solution.How to achieve this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this, the iOS SDK does not provided any acces to the call log.

Comment: No it will not be accepted, since you a have to use private methods which is not allowed or b have to acces a file which is not in the sandbox of you app which is therefor not accessible to you.