# Xamarin, iOS, Callkit and dialler

Tags: xamarin.ios, callkit

I have a code based on https://github.com/softsan/callkitsample. Everything works, but when during a call I tap on green phone icon, nothing happens. I would like that  window with call details would appear, like it is during regular phone call. Any idea how to do it?
I'm quite new to Xamarin.
Calls are working (I can accept and make a call). I just would like to avoid writing my own view controller for "call in progress" UI..

Comment: Is there any error message in the console?

Comment: No error. Actually I wanted to see the same screen that appear after accepting incoming call : a full window with a call details, keypad etc . Is this possible without writing an own dialler as view controller ?

Comment: Hope this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625415/how-to-invoke-our-app-and-get-the-details-from-incoming-call) will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I'm looking for :-( It seems I wasn't precise enough, my fault: when call is incoming, accepting it shows "default" iOS calling UI, which is fine. Now I would like to have the same behavior for outgoing calls, without writing my own view controller. 

Incoming and outgoing calls are working in the app ; I just worried UI behavior

Comment: According to this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331814/call-indicator-bar-is-not-responding-for-audio-and-video-call) it seems that you need to create the UIView yourself.