# Access to recent calls on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, addressbook

Is there any LEGAL way to access the recent calls (calls history)  on the iPhone by code? I saw a few options but they said that apple won't accept it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone call log / history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history)

Answer (score 1):

You may access call history via undocumented APIs but, you will not be able to publish your app on appstore as apple does not allow/approve any application which by any means use undocumented APIs