# Read Call History from iPhone on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios4, ios7

My application needs to access the call history of the `iPhone`, it's possible to access

```
"/private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db" since iOS 5.
```

So i had like to know if Apple has changed the security in `iOS7` to allow third party apps to access the `"call_history.db"`

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history

Comment: This is not a duplicate. None of those questions have been suitably answered and the ones that have work only for <6.0.

Comment: Have a look at this link, this website challenge this functionality

https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has never allowed or provide API for third-party application to read your call log history.  Third-party apps can only read files outside of its sandbox if the phone is jailbroken.

Comment: I see! how is this application doing it then? i wonder!! http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/ just download the free version. on the file list you would see Library/CallHistory/call_history.db
which is an un encrypted sqlite data file. it would wrok even if your phone is not jailbraked

Comment: Once the call_history.db is copied/sync/backed up to a Mac or Windows computer you can do whatever you want to do with it. (Note: iTunes has an option to encrypt all backups)  The question above is related to an iOS app reading the call history log while running on the device itself.  You cannot.