# Can we get iOS cell id and last call log report?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get Cell ID in iOS?

And can we get last call log report like last call duration, time&date?

Comment: No, there are privacy implications.

Answer (score 1):

We `don’t have call_history.db access`. Also, there is no public API to access the call log.
Callkit framework: Here you cannot access call log but you can Identify incoming calls, block calls….

> Callkit
>       Display the system-calling UI for your app’s VoIP services, and coordinate your calling services with other apps and the system.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. Apple does not provide a public API to call log. Though you can monitor incoming calls, block some calls e.t.c

check out this thread here [Is there an iOS API for accessing call logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753644/is-there-an-ios-api-for-accessing-call-logs)