# How can I retrieve call history on an iPhone using Flutter or native iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, calllog-ios

After reading many blogs,Stackoverflow [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33754206/5197712)  and conducting research, I have concluded that there is no API for retrieving call logs in iOS. However, after installing Truecaller, when I access the call log and caller screen as well, Truecaller shows spam calls. How did Truecaller implement this functionality?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't. They implement a CallKit call identification extension. They register known numbers and names for those numbers with iOS. The app itself has no access to the caller details. https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial