# Get call history in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want details of dial calls,received calls and missed calls in a form of Array or List.
So, That I can display that records in UITableView of my app.
Please suggest me code for button touch up event instead of suggesting any links.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history

Comment: @ioslearner those are all very outdated information and links in the answers

Comment: If you search for "iOS call history" here on SO then you'll find *many* similar questions with answers ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Not possible.

Luckily that is not possible. That kind of data and information is far too private to be accessible for everyone.

Something like that can only be achieved via private APIs or on jailbroken devices - both will not get you into the app store.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to access such private information