# iOS - Check calling contact inside own App and display name

Tags: ios, xcode, contacts

I have an app that manages contacts. Now my question, when a call is incomming and the number is not recognized from inside the ios contacts (so just the number without name is displayed), is it possible to forward that number to my app, search for an contact, and if found dispay its name on the phone?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone call log / history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history)

Comment: No, it's not possible. Please search before you ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214725/iphone-call-log-history

Comment: That is not what I am asking. I want to change the display text while the phone is ringing. But I guess since its not possible to get the event of a "new call" it won't be possible to trigger anything when a new call comes in